# Relative latency of playing, pausing/stopping, and setting volume of audio in Android

Tags: android, audio, latency

My question is about the relative latency of playing, pausing/stopping, and setting volume of audio in Android. Specifically: whether it's the same or lower latency to pause/stop an audio clip than to play it, and likewise whether it's the same or lower latency to set the volume of a clip (or of the system volume) than to play it.

For context, suppose the latency of playing an audio clip in Android is 150ms, i.e. SoundPool.play is executed at T=0m and the end-user hears the sound at T=150ms.

At T=200m, the program executes SoundPool.pause. If the pause latency is also 150m, that means the pause won't be heard by the end-user until T=350m, after they have heard 200m of the clip. If, however, the pause latency is, say 50m, then the sound will stop at T=250m, after only 100m has been head by the end-user.

Obviously latency isn't constant, exact, or consistent across devices, so to be more precise, what I'm really asking is whether Android uses a separate pathway or technique to pause/stop/change volume of audio (either program-specific or system-wide volume) that is inherently lower-latency than the way audio is played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up Play takes more time as it has to initialize the play the following actions takes path

1. find the MIME type of the media file, this needs parsing of the media format and looks for specific header
2. initialize audio decoder(usually hardware), the OMX decoder has to be loaded into memory
3. setup the buffers say allocate 10 buffers in the parser and 10 buffers in the decoder.
4. Setup the paths between parser and decoder and playback audio device (Speaker)
5. Play happens at this step, data flows from parser buffers to decoder buffers,  when the decoder buffers are filled, OMX (decoder framework) will notify player engine, engine passes the buffer data to AudioManager -> AudioTrack etc.
6. Decoder will again process the data from Parser buffers and this process goes on until EOF or user press pause/stop

During pause latency should be much low than play because, only the data exchnage is paused, but buffers are not released.

During stop buffers are released and player is also released, so need to do same process for play again if user needs to play again.

Volume up and down is simple calls to AudioManager to adjust the call voleumes. So its latency should be lower than play/stop

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you have any references for this? Is your answer based on Android documentation or your examination of the source code?

Comment: Based on Android source code, check android/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp, OMXCodec.cpp etc.                                                                            You can see source code for parsing Audio/Video (AACExtractor, MPEG4Extractor etc), Writers (AACWriter, MPEG4Writter) for making video (Camera) etc